# How can we set the video quality for HLS streaming in iOS?

Tags: ios, avplayer

Following is the code I am using for playing HLS contents

```
 let url = URL(string: "https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8")
 let playerItem =   AVPlayerItem.init(url: url)
 playerItem.preferredPeakBitRate = 20000
 let player = AVPlayer.init(playerItem: playerItem)
 let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
 controller.player = player
 present(controller, animated: true) {
            player.play()
  }
```

But in the logs I can see that the used bitrate is around 25000 but I have set the preferedPeakBitRate as 20000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the preferredPeakBitRate [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeritem/1388541-preferredpeakbitrate) there is the following message:

If network bandwidth consumption cannot be lowered to meet the preferredPeakBitRate, it will be reduced as much as possible while continuing to play the item.